# Deploying spring boot hibernate application into Tomcat server

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I know it is already asked but I didn't find the solution to the problem yet. I have a Spring Boot application which uses spring-boot-starter-data. I'm trying to deploy  the application in Tomcat server (v.8.5.38) using Docker but I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
```

As it was suggested in other post, I downgraded both javax validation and hibernate validator versions to 1.0.0.GA and 4.3.1.Final

When I did this I got this error:

```
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.Validator]: Factory method 'mvcValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [catalina.jar:8.5.38]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.Validator]: Factory method 'mvcValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

As I could read in related posts, it is something related to hibernate-validation versions, but I dont know how to fix it.

Here are the dependencies I am using (before doing the downgrade):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Maven dependency tree:

```
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile

(...)

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
```

Thanks in advance